# Function does not return value

Tags: solidity, remix

The function `caller()` below does not return any value

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract M2M{

    function setvalues(uint a ,uint b) returns (uint){
        return a;
    }


    function caller() public returns (uint) {
      return  setvalues({b:90,a:45});
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hum.. your input does not seem to be a uint, am I wrong?

Comment: Since `caller` doesn't have `view` nor `pure` modifiers remix assumes they are part of a transaction. You should add one of those modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a try executing your code in remix and I am able to get the return value as 45 ,which is the expected output. Make sure you have the contract defined as a separate sol file or inject the dependencies if it's used with other contract.

[image]